# Laravel Typeahead cannot find DB items

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, typeahead.js

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and Typeahead.js to populate a form using DB element. As I'm new in this platform, I'm following [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-smart-search-with-laravel-and-typeahead-js) to build this form. I've followed everything but **search result finds nothing** from my DB.

Here's the details,

### Item Table

```
id | name | price
1  | Shoes| 4500
2  | Bags | 2500
```

### Item Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Nicolaslopezj\Searchable\SearchableTrait;
use DB;
.................
........

use SearchableTrait;

protected $searchable = [
    'columns' => [
        'items.name' => 10,
        'items.id' => 8,
    ],
];

public $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'price'];
```

### routes\web.php

```
Route::get('test', 'SearchesController@index');
Route::get('finditems', 'SearchesController@finditems');
```

### SearchesController.php

```
use App\Item;
.....................
..........
    public function index(){
        return view('test');
    }

    public function finditems(Request $request){
        return Item::search($request->get('q'))->get();
    }
```

### views\test.blade.php

```
<form class="typeahead" role="search">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
   <input name="q" type="search" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search Items" autocomplete="off">
</form>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Options for "Bloodhound" suggestion engine
        var engine = new Bloodhound({
            remote: {
                url: '/finditems?q=%QUERY%',
                wildcard: '%QUERY%'
            },
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('q'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
        });

        $(".search-input").typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            source: engine.ttAdapter(),

            name: 'itemsList',

            templates: {
                empty: [
                    '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown"><div class="list-group-item">Nothing found.</div></div>'
                ],
                header: [
                    '<div class="list-group search-results-dropdown">'
                ],
                suggestion: function (data) {
                    return '<a href="' + data.id + '" class="list-group-item">' + data.name + '- @' + data.price + '</a>'
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** I've used `Route::get('finditems/{q}', 'SearchesController@finditems');` in my route file. But same result!

### Edit - It Works!

Its working actually! I forgot to use `composer require "nicolaslopezj/searchable:1.*"`

Comment: I'm not sure this part is right : `($request->get('q'))->get()`

Comment: It's Working. Thanks for your comment. I forgot to use: `composer require "nicolaslopezj/searchable:1.*"`